# SQL Server: Consultar varios registros por ultima fecha en la misma tabla

Tags: sql-server-2005

Tengo mi tabla de base de datos, es una tabla historial, donde tengo registrado el historial de sueldos de mis trabajadores.

Necesito una consulta que me devuelva el último sueldo de cada trabajador a partir de 'x' fecha dada.

La idea parte de este código para otro reporte:

```
SELECT top 1 fecha, codigo_empleado, sueldo_mensual

from historial

where fecha < = fecha_dada and codigo_empleado = codigo_dado

order by fecha desc
```

La fecha y el código del trabajador vienen dados por el sistema (visual fox pro)

Con esta consulta no hay problema porque siempre tendré el último registro por fecha (gracias al TOP y al order desc).

Pero el problema está cuando quiero el ultimo registro de cada codigo de empleado.
Estoy usando sql server 2005, y entiendo que está un poco -o muy- descontinuado.

Datos de ejemplo:

```
fecha            codigo_empleado,    sueldo_mensual
2019-01-01       E001                  250000
2019-02-01       E001                  550000
2019-01-01       E002                  350000
2019-02-01       E002                  450000
2019-01-01       E003                   50000
2019-02-15       E003                  150000
```

Aquí hay 3 empleados, con dos sueldos distintos en los primeros dos meses de este año y busco el sueldo que tenían el 2019-15-02.

El resultado que busco es el ultimo sueldo que tenía cada empleado para la fecha arriba indicada, trayéndome los siguientes datos:

```
fecha            codigo_empleado,    sueldo_mensual
2019-02-01       E001                  550000
2019-02-01       E002                  450000
2019-02-15       E003                 150000
```

Aquí tendría a los empleados con su último sueldo a partir de la fecha que entregué: 2019-02-15.

Por ahora es la mejor explicación que puedo dar. Si hace falta explicar algo mas, me dicen.

Comment: ¿Puedes dar unos datos de ejemplo e indicar como debería ser el resultado final?

Comment: @JYass Listo. Te sirve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es relativamente simple usando `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY codigo_empleado ORDER BY fecha DESC) RN
    FROM dbo.historial
)
SELECT  fecha,
        codigo_empleado,
        sueldo_mensual
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

[**Aquí hay un demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c25435902209aeb1b637afe0b3a651c) con este código. Y los resultados son:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╗
║   fecha    ║ codigo_empleado ║ sueldo_mensual ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2019-02-01 ║ E001            ║         550000 ║
║ 2019-02-01 ║ E002            ║         450000 ║
║ 2019-02-15 ║ E003            ║         150000 ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra aproximación, siempre que tengas un único sueldo por fecha, es establecer en primer lugar cual es la máxima fecha por empleado y usar este dato como subconsulta para luego recuperar únicamente estas filas:

```
select h1.fecha,
       h1.codigo_empleado,
       h1.sueldo_mensual
       from historial h1
       inner join (select codigo_empleado,
                          max(fecha) as max_fecha
                          from historial
                          group by codigo_empleado
       ) h2
       on h1.codigo_empleado = h2.codigo_empleado
       and h1.fecha = h2.max_fecha
```